# Awk command failing during the redirection with null sting value

Tags: awk, gawk

I want to split the large file into pieces. Filename and the number records per file after split will be provided as arguments/variables to awk.

EG: `FILENAME=A_20` (say it has 100 records), `NoOfRecordsPerFile=50`
The splitted file names must be

```
A_20-1.txt
A_20-2.txt
```

The command I am using is:

```
awk -vNoOfRecordsPerFile -vFILENAME 'NR%NoOfRecordsPerFile==1{x=FILENAME"-"++i".txt"}{print > x}' $FILENAME
```

I am getting error :

```
awk: (FILENAME=A_20 FNR=1) fatal expression for `>' has null string value
```

Am I doing anything wrong.

The same command is working for the other file.

Comment: Which awk are you using? `-vFILENAME` and `-vNoOfRecordsPerFile` are not valid for mawk or GNU awk.

Comment: try double quotes for `x`.

Comment: I am using gawk

Comment: I tried doing this with the shell script variables as well. but the same issue. Command I used is
awk NR%"'$NoOfRecordsPerFile'"==1{x="'$FILENAME'""-"++i".txt"}{print > x} $FILENAME.
But still I get the same error. My filename is around 48 characters, this should not be a problem I think.

Comment: Your comment and question show different commands. Please edit your post to include the actual command you're running.

Comment: Hi Muru, after you said that GNU awk will not supoort variable declaration in the way i mentioned in my post, i tried the 2nd awk command i commented. So  tried these 2 awk commands.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `FILENAME` variable with an *empty* value (you never give `FILENAME` a value on the command line), this should produce an error even before your `awk` script starts running. `awk` already *has* a variable called `FILENAME` that you can use.  It's the name of the current input file.

Using `-vNoOfRecordsPerFile` you say you want to assign a value to an `awk` variable on the command line, but you never give it a value.  This should produce a different error from the one you say you're getting. If you wanted it to take the value of the shell variable with the same name, then use `-v NoOfRecordsPerFile="$NoOfRecordsPerFile"`.

So, the final `awk` command becomes:

```
awk -v NoOfRecordsPerFile="$NoOfRecordsPerFile" '
    ((NR-1) % NoOfRecordsPerFile) == 0 { x = FILENAME "-" ++i ".txt" }
                                       { print > x                   }' "$FILENAME"
```

Comment: OP says they're using GNU awk, and with gawk, I get an error if I try `-v FILENAME` without assigning a value: ``gawk: `FILENAME' argument to `-v' not in `var=value' form``

Comment: @muru They are 1) not using `gawk`, or 2) not getting the error they say they are getting, or 3) not running the code they say they are running.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the `NR%NoOfRecordsPerFile==1` condition that is not met before using the variable `x`, so that variable isn't set.

Instead of `awk`, you could use `split`:

```
split -l 50 -d --additional-suffix='.txt' --numeric-suffixes=1 A_20 'A_20-'
```

This splits the file `A_20` into 2 files of 50 lines called `A_20-01.txt` and `A_20-02.txt`.

---

If you want to use `awk`, you can try this:

```
awk -v lineno=50 '((NR-1)%lineno)==0{cnt++;f=FILENAME "-" cnt ".txt"}{print >>f}' A_20
```